# Singular Borel measures that are regular and the quotient of it's derivative over itself.

Tags: proof-verification, lebesgue-measure, radon-nikodym, singular-measures

Let $\lambda$ be a positive regular Borel measure such that $\lambda\perp m$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $E$ be Borel with positive $\lambda$ measure and on $E$
$$\limsup_{r\to 0^+}\lambda B(x,7r)/\lambda B(x,r)<\infty.$$
Then there is a closed subset $F$ of $E$ with $\lambda F>0$, a $r'>0$, and a $N>0$ such that if $r<r'$ then
$$\lambda B(x,7r)/\lambda B(x,r)<M$$
for $x\in F$.

I have a solution, but I wanted to prove it via the method below.

**Q1: Is this correct?** I just need to produce a uniform bound. Suppose I knew that
for every $x\in E$ there is a $r'$ such that if $r<r'$ then
$$\frac{\lambda B(x,7r)}{\lambda B(x,r)}<M.$$

It can be shown that the quotient above is continuous in $x$ for $x\in E$. Indeed, it can be shown that $\lambda B(x,r)$ is continuous. The hypothesis gives us the fact that $$\sup_{(0,r] }\lambda B(x,7r)/\lambda B(x,r)< \infty$$ for some $r$. This together with monotonicty gives us that $B(x,r)$ is of positive $\lambda$ measure for every $r$. 
Thus $E_r:=\{x\in F:\lambda B(x,7r)/\lambda B(x,r)\leq M+1\}$ is closed. For every $x\in F$ there is a $r_x$ such that $$x\in \bigcap_{r<r_x}E_r$$
We know that for $m$-a.e. $x$ $$\lambda B(x,r)/mB(x,r)\to 0.$$
So by construction $$ \bigcap_{r<r_x}E_r \subset F \text{  and  }F\subset\bigcup_{i=1} \bigcap_{r<1/i}E_r.$$

Using continuity from below gives us a sequence of closed sets and the claim follows.

**Q2: How to obtain the uniform bound:**
$$1\leq \lambda B(x,7r)/\lambda(B(x,r)=7^n\frac{\lambda B(x,7r)/m(B(x,7r)}{\lambda B(x,r)/mB(x,r)}\to \frac{0}{0}$$
 and for each $x$ we have an upper bound. Can I say anything about this limit?

Comment: Some authors use the convention that a "Borel regular measure" is one that (in addition to being a measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra) assigns finite measure to all compact sets.

Comment: That is the definition I am using: Finite on cpt sets and outer regular. But how does that help?

Comment: If you also assume inner regular (which in the question, you say "regular", so I was assuming both inner/outer regular), then the $\lambda$-measure of $E$ is the supremum of $\lambda$-measure of compact (in particular, closed) subsets of $E$, which have finite measure by Borel regularity.

Comment: I wasn't clear sorry about that. I mean't the standard definition and since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is such that every open set if $\sigma$ compact regular Borel measures are Radon.

Comment: You say you want to show there exists a closed set $F\subset E$ such that [...] on $F$. Assuming that "on $F$" means "for every $x\in F$" you can simply let $F=\emptyset$. Surely that doesn't do what you actually want, but it does do what you _said_ you want - you need to clarify the question.